# OpenCV with Python 3.6.4 on Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 import cv2: DLL not found

Tags: opencv, python-3.6

i'm having a problem with opencv installation but i dont know if it is due to the fact that i'm using that system or missing c++ libraries.. I get the message DLL Failed to load cannot find the specified module.
I tried installing c++ 2015 redistributable for 64bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was found by Jakub Mertl and documented [here](https://jakubmertl.com/blog/python-import-cv2-error):

Below I have repeated his procedure which solved the problem on my server:

1. Get all available windows updates and restart.
2. In powershell run command: Install-WindowsFeature -Name ServerEssentialsRole -IncludeAllSubFeature
3. Download Windows Server Essentials [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40837) Install it and restart your machine.

Comment: Thank you for your help Arne, I will try it!

Comment: I am using windowsserver 2012 at it solved my problem thanks so much

Comment: This worked for me in 2023. Thanks Arne.